# Two jQuery popup close functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery popup close function. But I have two different popup lightbox area. Problem is first popup close function not working but second popup close function is working.

First jQuery click close link is **not working**:

```
$('.kapat').click(function(){
    close_box();
});

$('.degistiralani').click(function(){
    close_box();
});
```

Second jQuery click close link is **working**:

```
$('.pclose').click(function(){
    close_box();
});

$('.cover_change_wrap').click(function(){
    close_box();
});
```

All of my jQuery code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $('.d_button').click(function(){
          $('.degistiralani, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
          $('.alan').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
          $('.degistiralani, .alan').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.kapat').click(function(){
          close_box();
        });

        $('.degistiralani').click(function(){
          close_box();
        });

      });

      function close_box()
      {
        $('.degistiralani, .alan').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
          $('.degistiralani, .alan').css('display', 'none');
        });
      }

    $(function(){

        $('.b_c_d_button').click(function(){
          $('.cover_change_wrap, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
          $('.kapak_degistirme_alani').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
          $('.cover_change_wrap, .kapak_degistirme_alani').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.pclose').click(function(){
          close_box();
        });

        $('.cover_change_wrap').click(function(){
          close_box();
        });

      });

      function close_box()
      {
        $('.cover_change_wrap, .kapak_degistirme_alani').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
          $('.cover_change_wrap, .kapak_degistirme_alani').css('display', 'none');
        });
      }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `close_box()` defined twice. You're overwriting the first definition. Give them different names and it should work. I changed your first one to `close_box1()`

```
$('.kapat').click(function(){
      close_box1();
    });

    $('.degistiralani').click(function(){
      close_box1();
    });

function close_box1()
  {
    $('.degistiralani, .alan').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
      $('.degistiralani, .alan').css('display', 'none');
    });
  }
```